# Git ignore files while cloning

Tags: git, github

I have got a git bare repository with the following contents

```
         HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

The info folder also contains info/mailist.txt and info/log

My question is that if the user is cloning this file then how to ignore these two files with the clone command

```
             git clone --bare main new --ignore //????????
```

Comment: Those files/directories you listed are used internally by git. Are you looking in the correct folder?

Answer (score 1):

After testing, I see that a `clone --bare` won't clone `info/log` and `info/mailist.txt`

```
$ /c/prog/git/tests/t2 (BARE:master)
$ l ../t1/info/
total 1
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ      240 Mar  1 09:20 exclude
drwxr-xr-x    7 VonC Administ        0 Mar  1 09:20 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ        2 Mar  1 09:21 log
drwxr-xr-x    2 VonC Administ        0 Mar  1 09:21 .

$ /c/prog/git/tests
$ git clone --bare t1 t2
Cloning into bare repository t2...
done.
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

$ /c/prog/git/tests/t2 (BARE:master)
$ l info/
total 1
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ      240 Mar  1 09:21 exclude
drwxr-xr-x    2 VonC Administ        0 Mar  1 09:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 VonC Administ        0 Mar  1 09:21 ..
```

Comment: If a user creates thiose files while cloning will it be ignored

Comment: @Rajeev: yes, in that those files seem to be always ignored.