# Is possible clone only a folder from remote repository?

Tags: git, download, clone

I want download only 2 folders from remote git repository. In this case is the ubuntu kernel git repository.
Download all kernel is a waste of time and bandwidth if I only want 2 folders.
Is there any way to do this with git?

Comment: Try to use `bare` flag.

[see there][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511088/git-ignore-files-while-cloning

Comment: @MaximShoustin: What? That has nothing to do with a sparse clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't create a partial clone

Answer (score 2):

No, not in the way you're asking. But you can do one of these:

1. download a tarball -- the repository's web-ui should offer such an option, otherwise you can use `git archive` ([man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), google and SO will help you with its usage); or
2. do a shallow clone, using the --depth switch; this will download only the given number of commits, so you don't get the whole history. The [`git clone` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) has more details about it.

Comment: Does `git archive` download and compress all repository?

Comment: It compresses exactly what you tell it to compress. The man page has a number of examples at the end, and as I said, Google will help too.

Comment: It seems that doesn't work: `$ git archive --remote=git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-raring.git debian            
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
`

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the Ubuntu Kernel team has disabled remote archiving for their repo. I seem to remember that can be done, but I can't find any documentation about that. Well, you can use the "snapshot" button on the web-ui to download a tarball, and extract only the folder(s) you want, or you can use the shallow clone+sparse checkout described in Kjuly's answer (once he's updated it).

Answer (score 1):

It seems Git **CANNOT** implement this.

I thought "**Sparse Checkout**" will works, but as @ HolgerJust said:

> This will still download the full remote repository. It just doesn't checkout all the files into the working copy, but they are still available in the local index.

He's right.

---

<strike>Yes, you can. You can use [**Sparse Checkout**](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout).</strike>

Here's a simple example:

```
$ mkdir destinationFolder
$ cd destinationFolder
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:Kjuly/iPokeMon.git
$ git config core.sparseCheckout true
$ echo 'Pokemon/Models/*' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
... echo more if you need
$ git pull origin dev
```

And finally, you'll get files:

> destinationFolder
>   - Pokemon
>   - - Models

Comment: This will still download the full remote repository. It just doesn't checkout all the files into the working copy, but they are still available in the local index.

Comment: yep, it seems so. Thank you @HolgerJust.

Comment: A combination of a *shallow clone* and a *sparse checkout* would produce the desired result -- but that's only actually worth setting up if you often want to get updates from the repo. If you only want to do this once, getting one revision with `git archive` or a shallow clone would suffice; you can then just delete the files you don't need.

Comment: Instead of a shallow clone, a shallow fetch (`git fetch --depth=1`) would work too, of course, and that would fit easily into your solution above. I haven't tried it, but it should produce exactly the desired result (even if it's a little more work)